# How can we manage text width while changing its X-offset in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to manage the width of the text along with the size of the screen when changing the x-offset of the text. If I'm changing the x-offset of the text it is going out of the screen, So I wish that if it goes off the screen it should wrap that text and take it to a new line.

As you can see in this image it is showing proper because text is not that long.

[image: This works fine when text is short]

But as soon as text get longer it is getting out of screen.

[image]

Here is my code for reference

```
var textCoordinate: LayoutCoordinates? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
var outerRadius by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
val topArea = 100.dp
val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp
val textYOffset = with(LocalDensity.current) {
    targets.coordinates.positionInRoot().y.toDp()
}
var outerOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f, 0f)) }

textCoordinate?.let {
    val textRect = it.boundsInRoot()
    val textHeight = it.size.height
    val isInGutter = topArea > textYOffset || textYOffset > screenHeight.dp.minus(topArea)
    outerOffset =
        getOuterCircleCenter(targetRect, textRect, targetRadius, textHeight, isInGutter)
    outerRadius = getOuterRadius(textRect, targetRect) + targetRadius
}

Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(targets) {
            detectTapGestures { tapOffset ->
                if (targetRect.contains(tapOffset)) {
                    onShowCaseCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
        .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
) {
    when (targets.showCaseType) {
        /**
         * Rounded ShowCaseView
         */
        ShowCaseType.SIMPLE_ROUNDED -> {
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                radius = size.maxDimension,
                alpha = 0.9f
            )
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                radius = targetRadius - 10f,
                center = targetRect.center,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
        }
        /**
         * Rectangle ShowCaseView
         */
        ShowCaseType.SIMPLE_RECTANGLE -> {
            drawRect(
                Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
                size = Size(size.width + 40f, size.height + 40f),
                style = Fill,
            )
            drawRect(
                Color.White,
                size = Size(rectSize.width + 15f, rectSize.height + 15f),
                style = Fill,
                topLeft = Offset(xOffset - 8, yOffset - 8),
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
        }
        /**
         * Rounded ShowCaseView with animation
         */
        ShowCaseType.ANIMATE_ROUNDED -> {
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                center = outerOffset,
                radius = outerRadius * outerAnimaTable.value,
                alpha = 0.9f
            )
            // draw circle with animation
            dys.forEach { dy ->
                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.White,
                    radius = targetRect.maxDimension * dy * 2f,
                    center = targetRect.center,
                    alpha = 1 - dy
                )
            }
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                radius = targetRadius,
                center = targetRect.center,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
        }
    }
}

    @Composable
fun ShowText(
    currentTarget: ShowcaseProperty,
    targetRect: Rect,
    targetRadius: Float,
    updateCoordinates: (LayoutCoordinates) -> Unit
) {
    var txtOffsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var txtOffsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.toFloat()

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .offset(
            x = with(LocalDensity.current) { txtOffsetX.toDp() },
            y = with(LocalDensity.current) { txtOffsetY.toDp() }
        )
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            updateCoordinates(it)
            val textHeight = it.size.height
            val possibleTop =
                targetRect.center.y - targetRadius - textHeight
            val possibleLeft = targetRect.topLeft.x
            txtOffsetY = if (possibleTop > 0) {
                possibleTop
            } else {
                targetRect.center.y + targetRadius - 140
            }
            txtOffsetX = it.boundsInRoot().topRight.x - it.size.width
            txtOffsetX = if (possibleLeft >= screenWidth / 2) {
                screenWidth / 2 + targetRadius
            } else {
                possibleLeft
            }
        }
        .padding(2.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = currentTarget.title,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Blue
        )
        Text(
            text = currentTarget.subTitle,
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            color = Color.Blue,

        )
    }
}
```

How can we manage this? is there any way?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Abhimanyu I have added code please check now